# NoReverseMatch with Django when the URL exists

Tags: python, django, url, exception

In a template, I have `{% url "news.views.article" article=article.id %}` where article.id is the ID of an article currently being displayed. My urls.py contains this:

```
url(r'^news/$', 'news.views.index'),
url(r'^news/article/(?P<article>\d{1,4})/$', 'news.views.article'),
```

However, when I load the page containing the above templatetag, I get this:

```
NoReverseMatch at /news/
Reverse for '"news.views.article"' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'article': 2}' not found.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it without the quotes around your view definition.

```
 {% url news.views.article article=article.id %}
```

You've already defined the view name, so this should work by calling the function by name.

Comment: An alternative is to keep the quotes and add `{% load url from future %}` to your template. That way you'll be ready for Django 1.5.

Comment: See [1.3 Release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi) and [1.4 Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url) (Forwards compatibility) for more on it

Answer (score 0):

The syntax with quotes around the view name works only for Django 1.5. Since you're probably using an older version, you should remove the quotes, or add in your template:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

and then use the quotes.

More info on the deprecation - [Django 1.3 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi)

Comment: I get nearly the same error: `Reverse for '"news.views.article"' with arguments '(2,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

Comment: @iyrag, yep, you're right, it wasn't the real problem. I've updated the answer with the actual explanation.